# Attempting to render two spinners leaves one not working

Tags: android

I am attempting to render two spinners on my Android activity. They both will have to take their item values from a `string.xml` resource file.

Here is how my code looks like currently:

```
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_helper)
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_helper)
public class HelperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.cultureSpinner)
    Spinner cultureSpinner;
    @ViewById(R.id.harvestSpinner)
    Spinner harvestSpinner;

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @AfterViews
    public void initialize() {
        initializeSpinners();
    }

    public void initializeSpinners() {
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cultures, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cultureSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.harvestValues, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cultureSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The style xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="beginning|end"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cultureSpinner"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <Space
            android:layout_height="3dp"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/harvestSpinner"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now when I launch the activity, The second spinner is displayed before the first one and the first spinner that is now for some reason below the second one, does not function. If I press it, the dropdown menu does not appear.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void initializeSpinners() {
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cultures, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cultureSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.harvestValues, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        harvestSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
```

Just try it. Hope its work.

Comment: Renaming the second one to `adapter1` does not change anythings at runtime, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. you have to use two different adapter for different spinners

Comment: The OP's code also _does_ have two different objects.

Comment: yes, you need to also create object  of adapter for harvestSpinner.

Comment: I agree, this line `adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.harvestValues, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` just creates a new instance of type adapter. So we've two different objects. Haven't ?

Comment: Yes. Like ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter,adapter1;

Comment: No, `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter,adapter1;` does not _create_ any objects. They are only placeholders for real objects' references of this type.

Comment: Well yes the answer could be worded better for future reference.